# Include scalar on active record relation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Starting with two tables

```rb
class Single
  has_many :manies

  def total_value
    manies.sum(:value)
  end
end

class Many
  belongs_to: single
  # also has an integer 'value'
end

singles = Singles.all.includes(:total_value, :total_value2)
singles.each {|s| s.total_value } # Makes a new sql call for each single
```

I need to list many singles, and for each single I need to total up all of the values for that single.  If I just call total_value it ends up with N+1 SQL calls.

It is pretty trivial to do this in a single raw SQL query, but I can't figure out how to tell active record to do it.

Grouping.. kindof works?

```rb
Many.group(:single).sum(:value)
=> {#<Single id: "d80b4132-7ef1-4fe1-a9e0-7da89c00d295">=>0.171322e4}
```

But it returns a hash, not an ActiveRecord relation.. not sure what that is going to do when I have thousands of singles but it doesn't seem good.

Plus.. now I want to add a second scalar on value2.  Still fairly trivial in SQL.

What I would prefer to do is use includes.. but I believe it only works on associations, and I can't figure out how to make has_one work on a scalar.

e.g. something like this

```rb
class Single
  has_many :manies
  has_one :total_value, -> { many.sum(:value) }
  has_one :total_value2, -> { many.sum(:value2) }
end

class Many
  belongs_to: single
  # also has an integer 'value'
end

singles = Singles.all.includes(:total_value, :total_value2)
singles.each {|s| [s.total_value, s.total_value2] } # already cached, does not make SQL call
```

Comment: `singles = Single.joins(:many).group(:id).select(Single.arel_table[Arel.star],Many.arel_table[:value].sum.as('many_sum_value'),Many.arel_table[:value2].sum.as('many_sum_value2'))`. Then each `Single` object will have virtual attributes of `many_sum_value` and `many_sum_value2`. As a side note your relationships seem a bit messed up. Should be "Single has_many :manies(sp?)" and "Many belongs_to :single" (rather than has 1)

Comment: thanks - fixed the stuff (my code has much more in it so I simplified but didn't actually run it)

I'll checkout .select and virtual attributes - was not aware of those!

Comment: If you post that as an answer I can accept it - otherwise I'll post it later